# Does this query require dynamic sql? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, dynamic

I want to select the parameters of a stored procedure and then check whether each parameter is null or not in a loop.

The problem I'm having is that when I want to evaluate the variable in the IF statement, it is not being evaluated correctly. I want to evaluate each parameter I stored in the table variable. I don't know the syntax for this...or maybe it isn't even possible?
Does this require Dynamic SQL? If so, when executing dynamic sql, the value of the variable will be out of scope so how do I deal with that?

I verified everything up to the IF statement works.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateBank
(
    @BankKey [smallint] = NULL,
    @Bank [varchar] (30) = NULL,
    @BankCode [char] (4) = NULL,
    @MasterBankCode [char] = NULL,
    @Bin [char] (6) = NULL,
    @WebSite [varchar] (50) = NULL,
    @isActive [bit] = NULL,
    @CreateDate [smalldatetime] = NULL
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

DECLARE @MaxRow TINYINT, @Count TINYINT
DECLARE @SPName VARCHAR (128), @CurrentRow TINYINT
SET @SPName = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) -- SP self-reference to find its current name

DECLARE @SPParametersList TABLE (ID INT Identity(1,1) Primary Key,
                                 ParameterName NVARCHAR (128), 
                                 DataType NVARCHAR (128),
                                 ParameterMode NVARCHAR (10))

CREATE TABLE #TempExec(ID INT Identity(1,1) Primary Key,
                       Num BIT)


    INSERT INTO @SPParametersList (ParameterName, Datatype, ParameterMode)
        SELECT PARAMETER_NAME,DATA_TYPE,PARAMETER_MODE
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
        WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = @SPName


    SET @CurrentRow = 1
    SELECT @MaxRow = ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) FROM @SPParametersList

    WHILE @CurrentRow <= @MaxRow
    BEGIN
        IF ((SELECT ParameterName FROM @SPParametersList WHERE ID = @CurrentRow) <> NULL)
        BEGIN
            SELECT 'Success' 
            SET @Count = @Count + 1 
        END
            SELECT 'Fail' 
        SET @CurrentRow = @CurrentRow + 1 

    END 

    SELECT @Count
```

I always get 'Fail' when I run this stored proc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line:

```
IF ((SELECT ParameterName FROM @SPParametersList WHERE ID = @CurrentRow) <> NULL)
```

to

```
IF ((SELECT ParameterName FROM @SPParametersList WHERE ID = @CurrentRow) IS NOT NULL)
```

You also need to initialize the @Count variable to 0:

```
    SET @Count = 0
    SET @CurrentRow = 1
    SELECT @MaxRow = ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) FROM @SPParametersList
```

Comment: Thanks for the fixes. After making these changes, now I see Count = 8 and all successes even if I call the SP with one parameter (EXEC UpdateBank 1).  In that case, I expect the count to be 7.

Comment: Ya, I think your going to have to use dynamic sql for that.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, as the parameters go out of scope when you run the dynamic sql.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was wondering. It's beginning to look more and more like that is the issue and it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is an example of a query that can be rewritten without the use of loops/cursors (most sql is in my experience...)

Does the query below give you your desired results?

```
with temp as
(
    SELECT '@BankKey' as ParamName
        UNION
        SELECT '@Bank'
)

SELECT COUNT(*) as myCount
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS as isp
        LEFT JOIN temp as t
        ON t.ParamName = isp.PARAMETER_NAME
        WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = @SPName AND t.ParamName is null
```

You should try to avoid using Loops/Cursors as much as possible.  SQL Server (and most DBMSs in general) are excellent at performing Set based operations and terrible at performing row based operations (loops/cursors).

Comment: I would like to count the amount of parameters that are null instead of having the "status" of each parameter

Comment: Updated.  The most important thing here is getting away from your Row based operations.  I hope you take this seriously or you will stagnate as a developer.  Good luck!

Comment: This would be evaluating the existence of the parameter instead of the actual value of the parameter I think. I would also have to specify the parameters in the "with" section and I would prefer to do it dynamically so if I add a parameter to the stored proc, the code would still work.

Comment: thanks for the advice on row based operations. I'll keep that in mind as I continue my coding journey  =)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is in the <> NULL which should

```
 IF EXISTS(SELECT ParameterName FROM @SPParametersList WHERE ID = @CurrentRow)
```

but I'm not sure what you want to achieve with that piece of code...

Comment: I want to evaluate whether each parameter is null or not in that statement. So the expression i want to build is IF(@BankKey IS NOT NULL) for the first iteration of the loop, IF(@Bank IS NOT NULL) for the second iteration...etc

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** "I always get **'Fail'** when I run this stored proc": you have forget the `ELSE` branch

```
IF ((SELECT ParameterName FROM @SPParametersList WHERE ID = @CurrentRow) /*<>*/ IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Success' 
    SET @Count = @Count + 1 
END
ELSE -- << here
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Fail' 
END
SET @CurrentRow = @CurrentRow + 1
```

**(2)** To count all `not null` parameters:

```
SELECT  @Count=COUNT(*)
FROM    @SPParametersList a
WHERE   a.ParameterName IS NOT NULL
```

To count all `null` parameters:

```
SELECT  @Count=COUNT(*)
FROM    @SPParametersList a
WHERE   a.ParameterName IS NULL
```

Note: if you want to test for `NULL / NOT NULL` you should use `column/@variable IS [NOT] NULL` operator and [SET ANSI_NULLS must be ON: `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).

Comment: SPParametersList would only have valid parameters in the stored procedure so this would always return 8 as the count for the IS NOT NULL query

Comment: (1) Check again the first solution. (2) Then, how you want to check parameters ?

Comment: Thanks for (1). I want to see whether the values of the parameters are null or not in (2) and that's my question